# Box API authentication jwt

Tags: box-api

I am kind of new to this field, so please be patient with me.

do I have to have a server side when working with JWT and Box? My original aim was to implement only a simple React/Angular application for my users and issue perpetual tokens for them to use as a kind of a log-in.

It now seems that I have to have some kind of a server that will issue temporal tokens, and use them each time in order to access Box with the client ID.

This actually means that I need to add another authentication layer on top of Box for my users. Otherwise I have to keep private keys and/or other secrets in the JS, which IMHO not quite safe.

Please help me understand if my understanding is correct.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answer received from Box support:

> "You are correct. You will need a server to generate the access token
>   on behalf of your users. If you do this on the client side, it would
>   expose your credentials to your users".

we will try do make this work as a Box Integration solution rather then Box platform custom application.